# Problem occurs when using EGit for cloning repository in Eclipse (Missing unknown)

Tags: eclipse, egit, git-clone

there.
  I am using EGit to import a project into Eclipse under Ubuntu 10.10. But at the end of the import, Eclipse complains as follows:

`Git repository clone failed.`

`Missing unknown`

`f499261f24471928b916bf066d018d995bcaccd9`

Here is the git link: git://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun.git

Can anyone gives a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314853
However, upon further research, updating to the latest nightly build of EGit and a full update on my Eclipse repositories fixed it.

Comment: Be sure to accept this as a answer! :D Updating to the latest nightly build also helped me.