# Git Push results Missing unknown

Tags: git, egit

I am having an issue while pushing a commit to remote repo; let me describe what i have done.

1. i have created a local branch from master branch and commit one change.
2. then i have commit few more changes using the "Amend preveous commit" eGit feature.
3. I have merged the newly created branch to master branch
4. now initiate the team > push branch > press Next > press finish

It gives the missing unknown error message .

> ssh://git@rtsgit.bordingdata.dk/vikingclient.git: Missing unknown
>   263eabe8c9db3ca375269e6421e282082bbaae98

please the screen shot for details.
[image]

Comment: Copy and paste the error text. The screenshot is not readable !

Comment: error text added. (btw if you just zoom in CTRL++ you can see the screen shot clearly )

Comment: Are you using git submodules? If yes, this looks like a duplicate of [Problem occurs when using EGit for cloning repository in Eclipse (Missing unknown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595742/problem-occurs-when-using-egit-for-cloning-repository-in-eclipse-missing-unknow).

Comment: no i am not. i do not think it is related to  Egit version. tried in latest EGit version. it is  same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go over following steps

1. Start `eclipse` in vebose mode and check the log
2. Check the log for the `egit` plugin
3. Check the compability of your `egit` and `eclipse` versions.